# Safari 7 browser hangs on specific javascript. How to diagnose?

Tags: javascript, safari, cpu-usage, safari7

I got a [website](http://www.panoramahk.com), which contains some JavaScript & CSS. Not much fancy stuff is made, but it makes Safari 7 (version 7.0.2) hangs when changing language ( click the Chinese character on the right top corner ); CPU spikes to >100% and the wording "Design to Inspire", which is a GIF image hangs at the middle. How can I diagnose the JavaScript on that site?

Some [discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5556419?start=0&tstart=0) online suggests that the new feature of  Safari 7 to allow plugin to stop to save power is buggy, causing performance degradation. Yet, after disabled the feature, the issue persists.

On the other hand, some developers suggest that I can use Safari's Developer Panel to diagnose the performance, but the Panel hangs along with Safari. No usable data is captured.

Notes:

- Same issue does not appear in Chrome / Firefox / IE.
- Can't post all the codes here, as the JavaScript has over 1000 lines
- In Chrome, developer console tells my CPU usage of JavaScript is normal
- OS is Mac OS X 10.9.2
- Safari in Guest User still has the same issue
- Other software does not have major usage of CPU (i.e. CPU is almost idle)

[image: CPU usage]